# Displaying image from mysql db in PHP

Tags: php, html, image, echo

I'm getting some errors. I used longblob in mysql and I tried to echo it but it doesnt work.

Here are my variables:

```
$user_id = strip_tags($get_user_details['id']);
    $fullname = strip_tags($get_user_details['fullname']);
    $username = strip_tags($get_user_details['username']);
    $email = strip_tags($get_user_details['email']);
    $address = strip_tags($get_user_details['address']);
    $gender = strip_tags($get_user_details['gender']);
    $contact = strip_tags($get_user_details['contact']);
    $user_access_level = strip_tags($get_user_details['user_levels']);
    $passwd = strip_tags($get_user_details['password']);
    $picture = strip_tags($get_user_details['picture']);
```

and here is where I echoed it:

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 " align="center"> <img alt="User Pic" src="<?php echo $picture; ?>" class="img-circle img-responsive"> </div>
```

Comment: What errors?  What is the value of `$picture`?

Comment: The issue, as per the duplicate, is that you've stored it as a blob and this is a binary string. So when you fetch it from the DB and attempt to use it, it essentially is nonsense. Look at the duplicate and amend code

Comment: Virtually impossible to answer as the question is devoid of sufficient information and the code snippets give no hint of what might be wrong